# Android simultaneous audio and video in a WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, youtube-api, soundmanager2

I have been tampering around with an app of mine trying to port it to a an android `WebView`. The app has a video and an audio. Depending on the position of the audio track the video shows something different. Now this is easy enough in a Desktop platform, but when I try this on android the browser it doesn't seem to work. After enabling javascript and some more tweaks I'm still at at the beginning.

I if I use a `myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` then I get similar results to browsing the webapp with the android-mobile version of the Chrome browser. Which is less than ideal because it only allows one simultaneous stream which means that the video is stopped when the audio is played and the other way around(ie. the audio is automatically stopped the moment the video starts playing).

Is there anything like an android equivalent of the ios `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction`?

Thanks.